# How to set Owner column as created by?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have owner column and I want to fill automatically as created by?

How can I do it?

thanks,

Comment: What are you using to add new item? Default form or custom code?

Comment: I use Default form

Comment: Then you can do that using workflow or event receiver

Comment: What is the event receiver?

Comment: Just Rename your "Created By" Field to 'Owner' . If thats not possible then you need to build a custom workflow or custom event reciever

Answer (score 1):

you can try below trick,

1. Create single line text column with name 'Owner'.
2. add default calculated value

   ```
   =[Me]
   ```

   [image]

Limitation: It will show user login's.

Answer (score 1):

Workflow would probably be the easiest and safest solution.  Just create the workflow with the parameters:

```
Update List Item in [Current Item]
List: Current Item
*Add
  Set this field: Owner (your field name)
  To this value: Fx, (Data Source) Current Item, (Field From Source) Created By
```

Then end the workflow.

It won't be updated realtime as in seeing it populated in a field as a form is being filled out, but if you don't require the person entering it to see it, there won't be a need for all the JS or the use of SPServices on the New Form.aspx to set a field.

Answer (score 0):

We can also achieve it through client side code. Here I have given example using JavaScript object model.

1. Create an Owner column as "Single Line of Text"
2. Open List's new form in Edit mode
3. Add the Script Editor or Content Editor web part to the bottom of the page.
4. Insert the below script to update the Owner textbox with current user name,

Note: In the code snippet, replace the fieldid with the Owner column's field id.
Or, you can get the Owner column textbox id and replace with OwnerFieldId variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ownerFieldId="Owner_"+<fieldId>+"_$TextField";

function updateUserinTextBox() {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.website = context.get_web();
    this.currentUser = website.get_currentUser();
    context.load(currentUser);
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    document.getElementById(ownerFieldId).value = currentUser.get_title();
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(updateUserinTextBox, "sp.js");
</script>
```